# Alternative to inner join on very slow server 2

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, memory, optimization

I have a very simple mysql query on a remote windows 7 server on which i cannot change most of the parameters. I need to execute it only once now, to create a table, but in upcoming projects i'll be confronted to the same issue.

The query's the following, and has been running for 24 hours now, it's a basic filtering query :

```
CREATE TABLE compute_us_gum_2013P13
SELECT A.HHID, UPC, DIVISION, yearweek, CAL_DT, RETAILER, DEAL, RAW_PURCH_QTY,
UNITS,VOL,GROSS_DOL,NET_DOL, CREATE_DATE
FROM work_us_gum_2013P13_digital_purchases_with_yearweek A
INNER JOIN compute_us_gum_2013_digital_panelists B
on A.hhid = B.hhid;
```

Table A is quite big, around 250 million lines.
table B is 5 million lines
hhid is indexed on both tables, i haven't put a unique index in table B though i could, but will it change things dramatically ?

My ram of 12 GB is completely saturated (actually there's 1GB free but i think mysql can't touch it). Of course i closed everything i could, and the processor is basically not used. The status of the query has been stuck on "sending data" for most of the time.

Table A has also a cover index on 7 column, that i could drop as it's not used, but i don't think it would change something would it ?

One big issue i have is i cannot test a lot of things because i wouldn't know if it works until it works, and i think this query will be long no matter what. Also I don't want to lose for nothing the computation time that's already been spent.

I could also if it helps keep only the columns HHID, UPC and yearweek (resp bigint(20),bigint(20),and int(11), though the columns i would drop are only decimal and dates.

And what if i split table B in several parts ? the operation is only a filtering one, so it can be done in several steps, would i win time ? If i don't gain time but don't lose either, at least i could see my progress.

Another possibility would be to directly delete rows from table A (and if really necessary, columns), so i wouldn't have to write another table, would it be faster ?

I can change some database parameters if i send an email to my client, but it take some tim and is not suitable for a lot of tweeking and testing.

Any solution would be appreciate, even the dirtiest one :), i'm really stuck here.

EDIT:

Explain gives me this:

```
Id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     keylen  ref             row     Extra
1   Simple      B       index   hhidx           hhidx   8       NULL            5003865 Using Index
1   Simple      A       ref     hhidx           hhidx   8       ncsmars.B.hhid  6       [nothing]
```

Comment: That is a lot of data, I would start by trying to reduce the table size by looking for any redundancy and eliminating it with an association table. What kind of relationship do the tables share? Have you done an explain on the query to ensure everything is indexed properly? You can try mysqltuner to get some tips on your mysql configuration also. http://mysqltuner.com/

Comment: "And what if i split table B in several parts ?" I think this your own idea is a good one. Or can you add a filter criteria to either table A or table B data? Such as on CREATE_DATE or DIVISION, etc.?

Comment: You should edit the question and include the execution plan (prepend `explain` to the query).

Comment: @xd6_: yes, explain tells me that both indices on hhid, i cannot reduce table size, and the only relationship they have is hhid, table B is just a list of household ids basically. Thanks for advising mysqltuner, i will look into this though i can't use it in this case as i cannot install anything on this server.

Comment: @JosephB Alright, maybe i should try this then, find a field with 10 to 20 distinct values, index it, add a "where" to my query and run it several times. Is that what you're suggesting ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff
Edited in the end of my post, thanks

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I was actually suggesting that if you can find a field, which you can use to filter the data, then you'll join with only a subset of the full table, and therefore improve the performance.

Comment: @JosephB I see, that means creating subtables, reindexing them, and running the query on each one. Maybe that's the way...

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper When I look at the explain statement, I wonder why no `eq_ref` is used instead of the `ref` (see [this manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html)). I cannot say anything about the gain/loss though.

Comment: One more thing. _i haven't put a unique index in table B_: This could make a difference. Does table `A` have a unique index? If **not**, the result of your join could be up to 5mio*25mio rows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Engine? Is it InnoDB?
What are the primary keys for both tables?
Did you start both primary keys with your HHID (if HHID is not a candidate key for a table - you can create composite key and start it from that field)?
If you start both PK from HHID and then will join your tables on that field - disk seek will be reduced dramatically so you should see much better performance. If you cannot alter both tables - start from smaller one - alter its PK to have HHID on the first place of it and then check execution plan.

```
   ALTER TABLE compute_us_gum_2013_digital_panelists ADD PRIMARY KEY(HHID, [other necessary fields (if any)])
```

Suppose it will be better than before.

Comment: It's true i didn't bother to mention primary key explicitely on any table, it cannot be hhid on table A though because it's not unique (and no field is on table A). For a composite key I would need to take almost all the columns, i'm afraid of the the time required by the index building in this case. But I'll trust you and try this, i'm gonna kill this 30 hours query now and start over :(.

Comment: dont add all the fields to PK. Make composite one but with minimal length. Maybe it will be better to add some surrogate key and use it as second part of PK in addition to your join field. Anyway I ran PK recreation on small tables (~10 millions records) on prod and it didnt take much time...
The main performance issue in your case is bad clustering index. Your data is clustered around some hidden PK and you are trying to access it in random order.If you add PK and if your PK will start from HHID - your data will be clustered around it.It means sequential access, not random one.Which is faster

Comment: Very interesting explaination thank you, I didn't know about surrogate keys either. Right now i ran a script taking into account several advices from this page, if tomorrow morning it's still not OK I'll look deeper into that.